# How can I execute a .Net application during a VSTS build task?

Tags: .net, msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I currently have a .Net console application that I use to perform build and release tasks. At the moment I run this application locally using PowerShell. The application effectively moves data between databases via web services.

I'm looking to automate build and release tasks using VSTS. It wasn't clear to me how I could run my console application in VSTS. I want to use my application in multiple projects.

This [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/add-build-task) suggests JavaScript build tasks can be created - but I don't really want to port my code.

Is there somewhere I can upload my console application into VSTS that I can then call using a PowerShell build task? Or can I create a bespoke build task that allows .Net code? Should I checkin my application as code?

How can I execute a .Net application during a VSTS build task?

Comment: yes,you can use vsts powershell task to run consoleapp.please go through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines

Comment: @Sivapalla, where would you place the console application within VSTS in this case?

Answer (score 4):

Couple of options. You could create a custom task and package the exe in the task.

Option two is commit the exe to source in a tools folder.

Option three. Store in blob storage and pull during your build.

Once it is on the machine you can use either the PowerShell or the Command Line task to run it.

Comment: Or stick it in Nuget package and pull it from package management

Comment: Or stick it in a Chocolatey package and pull it using One-Get.

Comment: You can install the executable on the build server and call it from a script (powershell/batch)

Comment: @jessehouwing When you say 'machine', does that mean I would need my own build agent (e.g. I can't use the VSTS hosted build agent)?

Comment: Right, on the hosted agent you need to use one of the other mentioned options.

Comment: @Donovan, is there any walk through documentation outlining how to package executable resources and other actionable resource in a custom task?